# Show only the highest shipping class cost without a plugin in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to display only the highest shipping class cost at WooCommerce checkout screen. If user has 2 products in cart with different shipping class costs, only the higher one should be calculated while the backend settings are set to calculate per class.

I've been doing some research on this and couldn't find a solution so I wrote a code on my own. It doesn't work, the checkout still calculates all shipping class costs for products in the cart.

```
function only_show_most_expensive_shipping_rate( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
      return $rates;

    $most_expensive_method = '';

    if ( is_array( $rates ) ) :
        foreach ( $rates as $key => $rate ) :

            if ( empty( $most_expensive_method ) || $rate->cost > $most_expensive_method->cost ) :
            $most_expensive_method = $rate;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;
    // Return the most expensive rate when possible
    if ( ! empty( $most_expensive_method ) ) :
        return array( $most_expensive_method->id => $most_expensive_method );
    endif;
    return $rates;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'only_show_most_expensive_shipping_rate', 10, 2 );
```

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: DId find this: [link]https://jeroensormani.com/only-show-freecheapestmost-expensive-shipping-in-woocommerce/

Comment: Thank you. The code from that website was taken from Quora, where I initially found it and updated. However, it's not working.